# JWT strings must contain exactly 2 period characters. Found: 1 (JAVA)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jwt

While decoding i am getting this exception.
I am using **io.jsonwebtoken**
When i am pasting the code in jwt decoder without any key i can see the payload data which is little confusing.

Encoding

```
public class JwtEncoding {

    // Sample method to construct a JWT
    public static String createJWT(String user_id, String sso_token) {
        try {
            String SECRET_KEY = "secretKey";

            // The JWT signature algorithm we will be using to sign the token
            SignatureAlgorithm signatureAlgorithm = SignatureAlgorithm.HS256;

            // We will sign our JWT with our ApiKey secret
            byte[] apiKeySecretBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(SECRET_KEY);
            Key signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(apiKeySecretBytes, signatureAlgorithm.getJcaName());

            Map<String, Object> tokenData = new HashMap<>();
            tokenData.put("user_id", user_id);
            tokenData.put("sso_token", sso_token);


            // Let's set the JWT Claims
            JwtBuilder builder = Jwts.builder()
                    .setHeaderParam("typ", "JWT")
                    .setClaims(tokenData)
                    .signWith(signatureAlgorithm, signingKey);

            // Builds the JWT and serializes it to a compact, URL-safe string
            return builder.compact();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Decoding

```
public class JwtDecoding {

    public static Claims decodeJwt(String token) {
        String SECRET_KEY = "secretKey";
        try {
            Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
                    .setSigningKey(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(SECRET_KEY))
                    .parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
            return claims;

        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Error

> io.jsonwebtoken.MalformedJwtException: JWT strings must contain
>   exactly 2 period characters. Found: 1

Comment: Getting this error at the time of decoding

Comment: What's the value returned by createJWT()? What's the value passed to decodeJwt()?

Comment: @JBNizet here is the token - eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJqdGkiOiJXQU5NbldQTE4iLCJpc3MiOiJjMTNiNjM5Ni1mMzdiLTQwOGYtODc2My0zYTA2OWRhNzEyZjQifQ.Aa2Znn1AonEwYK-ZNk4b8ICT6lO7CVJ90kZSxKfxNNs

Comment: That doesn't answer my questions.

Comment: createJWT() return the encoded token that i have posted and i pass the same to decode and get the values

Comment: What matters is the value of the token that decodeJwt() receives when it throws the exception. The message indicates that it has only one dot. So, unless there is a huge bug in your library, which is probably not the case, you're not actually passing that token to the method, but another value. The problem is in code you didn't post. Use your debugger, and trace the value of the token at each point of the calling chain.

Comment: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJqdGkiOiJXQU5NbldQTE4iLCJpc3MiOiJjMTNiNjM5Ni1mMzdiLTQwOGYtODc2My0zYTA2OWRhNzEyZjQifQ.Aa2Znn1AonEwYK-ZNk4b8ICT6lO7CVJ90kZSxKfxNNs " this is the token that i pass to the decodeJwt() and it has 2 dots. This is the whole code that i am using to encode and decode the jwt token.

Comment: Then it should be very easy to create a very simple complete minimal test case showing that the library throws that exception even though the token has two preiods. And to then submit that test case in an issue to the library. But make sure to do that once your test case actually shows the issue. When I copy and paste your code and use the token you posted, I get "io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureException: JWT signature does not match locally computed signature. JWT validity cannot be asserted and should not be trusted.". So, either it's not the actual code you run, or it's not the actual token.

Comment: yes it is not the actual key.its just a place holder. where did u decode the token ? on the jwt site?

Comment: it would be much easier to help and to find out what's wrong if you could post actual code with actual keys and the actual output. Otherwise we waste time here. Of course we don't expect any secret production data, but it should be easy for you to prepare an example token with example key.